# Forge Edit2D customize toolset

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the Edit2D extension to draw a Polyline over the 2D model then the path of the polyline is sent to the designautomation API to draw the same polyline in the revit file.
The problem I'm having is that the designautomation is drawing the polyline correctly but the scale is incorrect, it doesn't match with what i'm seeing in the browser. The shape is fine, but the scale is not.
I assume that I need to customize the toolset to set the unithandler to use feet instead of inches. The documentation says to register a custom toolset this way:

```
edit2d.registerTools(MyToolSetName);
```

But there is no documentation on how to create the **MyToolSetName** toolset (i saw it's a complex object doing reverse engineering)
Any clue how can I set the unithandler and register it with the **registerTools** function?

Or any clue on how to make my 2D view in forge match the same coordinates as revit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Update (October 24th)

I built a sample on that, based on sheetviews translated from Revit files.
Please, refer [here](https://github.com/JoaoMartins-Forge/edit2d2da4r) for more details.
It takes advantage of [this blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/ja/node/1765).
As of now, it only works for sheetviews with viewports containing views that were also translated (present in the bubble generated).
Since we're drawing in 2D view, we only get X and Y from Viewer. Z components of the curves are defined at workitem by the plane used for drawing.
There's also a video on the sample [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hwf2kOwfy2I&feature=youtu.be)

Please refer [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/edit2d-use/) for details about using Edit2D Toolset (specifically under 3.2 Units for Areas and Lengths) as it says:

> Edit 2D uses the same units and length calibration as the MeasureExtension. You can use MeasureExtension’s calibration panel to specify units and calibration for your Edit2D shapes.

We also have a sample that does a similar flow (without Edit2D) [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-sketchit-revit)